# To prove that $ \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$, how do we choose $\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Could someone please explain to me what delta would work for this proof?
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty.
$$

My professor used $\delta = -1/\beta$, but I don't understand how that makes sense.

Comment: It's hard to tell because $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1x\ne -\infty$.

Comment: but this is wrong: the limit is 0

Comment: guys sorry I copied the wrong question. I have made the changes. its x--> 0

Comment: Your limit is only true if $x$ approaches $0$ from the left

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: I changed the question, could you tell me why delta = (-1/Beta) would work?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, $\beta$ appears in the **definition** of an infinite limit that you were given. It might have been stated as:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to a-} f(x) = -\infty$ if for every $\beta<0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<\beta$ whenever $-\delta<x-a<0$.

In your situation, you look for $\delta $ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{x}<\beta \quad\text{whenever } -\delta<x<0
$$
Rearrange the desired inequality (on the left) to isolate $x$ on one side (be extra careful with negative quantities). You will get $x>-1/\beta$. This is the reason for choosing $\delta=-1/\beta$.

Comment: Thanks man, now I understand the beta

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.
$$
\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{\beta}} =\ ?
$$